# SQL logic for inner join on (A AND B) OR NOT B

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I am looking to do an inner join as follows:

```
SELECT a.Account
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b 
  ON (a.Account = b.Account AND a.Source IN (SELECT Source FROM TableC))
  OR a.Source NOT IN (SELECT Source FROM TableC)
```

Is there a more simple or efficient way to accomplish this?

Some examples of the data:

TableA (Account, Source):

```
Account | Source
------------------
111     | florida
222     | florida
333     | georgia
444     | alabama
555     | new York
```

TableB (Account):

```
Account
-------
111
222
333
```

TableC (Source):

```
Source
-------
florida
alabama
```

Comment: I have added more specific example to help explain the problem. This is for SAP HANA space, but I believe the support would be better for any other SQL environment. 

I believe if I see an answer in one, I will hopefully be able to derive the logic that I need.

Comment: (A AND B) OR NOT B just means A OR NOT B in 2VL & SQL 3VL. (Evaluate for B true, false & null.) However, x NOT IN t is not NOT x IN t when there can be nulls. So this is not a case of (A AND B) OR NOT B unless there are no nulls. PS In code questions please give a [mre]. PS That includes any null constraints. Constraints need not be known to query, but they matter when rewriting a query that did use knowledge of constraints. PS That includes a worded specification. Eg maybe your IN version fails you for nulls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the query can be rewritten by using two left joins and a `WHERE` clause, to avoid repeating condition `a.Source [NOT] IN (SELECT Source FROM TableC)`:

```
SELECT a.Account
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.Account = b.Account
LEFT JOIN TableC c ON c.Source = a.Source
WHERE 
    (c.Source IS NOT NULL AND b.Account IS NOT NULL)
    OR c.Source IS NULL
```

This means: a record in `TableA` is selected either if both joins succeed, or if the join on `TableC` did not succed.

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I am unsure that I get what you mean. I see a `JOIN` so I assume a 1-1 relationship between both tables being joined in the conditional expressions...

Comment: Yes agreed, there could be multiple matches. But in the conditions in the `on` clause, there are only two records, one coming from each table. So what is the point for `IN` instead of equality?

Comment: @DaleBurrell: well, you were right after all... The question was substiantially changed and all of a sudden what you were saying made sense to me!

Comment: Sorry for the change! I realized that how I explained it was not correct. Appreciate your patience with an inexperienced member.

Answer (score 0):

My first inclination is to move all the conditions to the `where` clause:

```
SELECT a.Account
FROM TableA a
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM b WHERE a.Account = b.Account) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC c WHERE c.Source = a.Source)
      ) OR
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableC c WHERE c.Source = a.Source);
```

This has the advantage that you do not need to worry about duplicate results, if `b` has multiple rows for an account.

With appropriate indexes (on `b(Account)` and `c(Source)`), this should have very good performance.

The one exception where a `JOIN` would be helpful is when `b` is very small relative to `a`.